# Slider backgrounds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slider and need to change backgrounds without using .style.backgroundImage. So how can I do it with adding some class to slider or smth else?

```js
'use strict'

let backgroundSlides = ['url(\'/images/slider/burger-background.jpg\')',
  'url(\'/images/slider/pizza-background.jpg\')',
  'url(\'/images/slider/soup-background.jpg\')',
  'url(\'/images/slider/sushi-background.jpg\')'
];

let sliderElement = document.querySelector('.slider');
let sliderBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-button');

for (let i = 0; i < sliderBtn.length; i++) {
  sliderBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    sliderElement.style.backgroundImage = backgroundSlides[i];
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-btns">
        <input type="radio" name="slider button" id="slider-btn-1">
        <label class="slider-button" for="slider-btn-1"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="slider button" id="slider-btn-2">
        <label class="slider-button" for="slider-btn-2"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="slider button" id="slider-btn-3">
        <label class="slider-button" for="slider-btn-3"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="slider button" id="slider-btn-4">
        <label class="slider-button" for="slider-btn-4"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**With classes:**
Create for every input a class and set the background image in them.

```
<style>
  .slider-btn-1 {background-image: url('/images/slider/burger-background.jpg');}
  .slider-btn-2 {background-image: url('/images/slider/pizza-background.jpg');}
  .slider-btn-3 {background-image: url('/images/slider/soup-background.jpg');}
  .slider-btn-4 {background-image: url('/images/slider/sushi-background.jpg');}
</style>
```

Now you must only change the class attribute.

```
<script>
let sliderElement = document.querySelector('.slider');
let sliderBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-button');

for(let i = 0; i < sliderBtn.length; i++){
    sliderBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        sliderElement.className = 'slider ' + sliderBtn[i].htmlFor;//Or another attribute where the className is in
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: I want to say that my code is working, cause labels are connected with input radio. I want to know can I resolve this task without using .style.backgroundImage. I need alternative way.

Comment: OK. I have update my answer to a example with classes.